# How to overlay two raster layers

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1

How to match two raster layers, I have one raster and a shapefile and I want to convert the shapefile into raster BUT I want it to have the same cellsize and its cells overlay (same positions) to the first raster.
I already set as a 'mask' the first raster in the Environments options, but the resulting raster cells doesn't overlay with the first raster.

Answer (score 4):

Set your existing raster as a snap raster in Environment Settings>Processing Extent when converting your shapefile to raster.

[image]

Comment: You can also set the cell size from the environment settings, its under Raster Analysis